# count in one column

Tags: sql

```
upd_date                id_sts     id_tsk
20/03/21 09:00        19          01
22/03/21 11:05        18          01
22/03/21 11:04        21          01
20/03/21 09:06        19          02
23/03/21 11:05        18          02
23/03/21 11:04        21          02
```

where id_sts 19 - open , 21 - in work and 18 close
The user creates a task and closes it after a while. Example: On March 20, the user created a task, it is open, then on March 22, the task is closed. The question is, how can I display this period when the tasks on March 21 and March 22 are open. There are id_user, open, close, and update task columns in one column. I thought you could use with us or count the days until this task has the status open. the request is correct, but here is the total number of open issues.

```
select count(a.*), date_trunc('day', sh.upd_status)  from f.f_task a
join f.status_hist sh
on a.idtask = sh.idtask
where b.id_status not in (17,18) 
group by date_trunc('day', sh.upd_status)
order by date_trunc('day', sh.upd_status)
```

Comment: a and b are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes sense, like sh for status_hist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of open tasks for every day in `status_hist`

```
select td.dupd, count(*) tasks_open
from (
  select distinct date_trunc('day', upd_date) dupd
  from status_hist) td
join (
  select id_tsk,
        max(case when id_sts = 19 then date_trunc('day', upd_date) end) dstart,
        max(case when id_sts = 18 then date_trunc('day', upd_date) end) dend,
  from status_hist
  group by id_tsk
) tsk on td.dupd between tsk.dstart and tsk.dend
group by td.dupd
```